# Evaluating the limit of $\frac{\lambda e^{x(t-\lambda)}}{t-\lambda}$ at infinities

Tags: integration, limits, exponential-function

Essentially I am trying to compute the following integral:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{x(t-\lambda)} dx $ and I arrive at $\left[\frac{\lambda e^{x(t-\lambda)}}{t-\lambda}\right]^\infty_{-\infty}$

And this should equal to $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}$ but I can't really understand why.

I can understand at least when the limit is $-\infty$, why it would equal $0$. But when the limit is $\infty$ how do we get any answer that is not $\infty$.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Your integral is divergent.

Comment: I believe that you are trying to find the moment generating function of exponential random variable. Please notice that the lower limit should be $0$ and the integral converges only if $t<\lambda$.